# Private file (video) timeout?

Tags: files

I'm wondering if the private file system has a timeout.
Because after many tries of watching a video uploaded by the file system both in public and private mode, with a low speed connection, the video from private always stops loading at around 20 minutes of playing. The same video, from public, works perfect ( it keeps loading after 20 minutes, until the end ).

I've tried on many computers, with different videos, always the same.

Can someone explain me how the private files works, so i can try to find a workaround.

Sorry for my english.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an issue with streaming video from the private folder because Drupal handles the permissions rather than apache. Use the [resumable download module](https://drupal.org/project/resumable_download) to overcome this. You should be able to enable the module and you are good to go.